# node.js get batch output on console

Tags: node.js, child-process, psexec

I am using a remote windows batch file through node.js in below script.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function lsExample() {  
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('PsExec64 \\\\xxx.xx.xx.xx -u username -p password cmd /c "C:\\work\\test"');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stder:', stderr);
}
lsExample();
```

It is working in background and completes successfully. The problem is , i am not getting batch file "test.bat" output in console. It just gives below output.

```
D:\angular\app\server\try>node try.js
stdout:
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com



Starting cmd on xxx.xx.xx.xx... xxx.xx.xx.xx...
cmd exited on xxx.xx.xx.xx with error code 0.
```

No output is shown in local console. Batch file is very simple,

```
echo batch start >output.log
FOR /L %%x in (1,1,10) DO echo %%x Hello Testing>>output.log
```

I also want to read output.log. Please suggest, if I am missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The node.js part is working, it shows the output of the invoked command (PsExec64) in the console, it seems more a systems programming problem. Anyway, reading this ( https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/downloads/psexec ) I would add -i to the PsExec64 options. (Disclaimer: I can't test it right now)

Comment: I tried with -i option but now it is giving error. (node:928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:928) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Well, it seems that -i was not the right option, now the exec is failing, the promise is rejected, and, as there is no catch. Surrounding the lsExample() invocation with a try/catch block and printing the error may help, but the main problem is how to get the remote output from PsExec64 and/or the cmd.

I've no knowledge in Windows administration, maybe some other person can help, or ask in http://serverfault.com. Good luck!